# Brain teaser, how to re-arrange a js object and change it's custom structure according to several rules

Tags: javascript, json

Here is a brain teaser, I've been fiddling with it and I cannot find a genera solution and a clever function to re-arrange the following js object:

```
var rawObject = {
    item1 : {
        name: 'cola',
        qty: '2',
        color: 'red'
        // ... (there can be as many properties, but the number and type is the same for all the items which hold cola)
        // for example, if item2 has a property test, item2, item3 and item4 have the same property
    },
    item2: {
        name: 'cola',
        qty: '3',
        color: 'red'
        ....
    },
    item3: {
        name: 'cola',
        qty: '2',
        color: 'green'
        ...
    },
    item4: {
        name: 'pepsi',
        qty: '2',
        color: 'red'
        ....
    },
    item5: {
        name: 'pepsi',
        qty: '3',
        color: 'red'
        ....
    },
    .....
}
```

The function should rearrange  the object into something like:

```
var obj = {
    cola: {
        1:  {
                qty: 2,
                color: 'red'
            },
        2:  {
                qty: 3,
                color: 'red'
            },
        3:  {
                qty: 2,
                color: 'green'
        }
    },
    pepsi : {
        1:  {
            qty: 2,
            color: 'red'
        },
        2: {
            qty: 3,
            color: 'red'
        }
    }
    .....
}
```

The hard part is that I don't have any control over the names and the properties.

I cannot do for loops and say: if (color ==== something) do something, because I will not always have a property called color.

Any ideas?

How would you do it?

I will post what I have tried myself, If I find something that actually works:)

Comment: Post what you have tried even if it not works, so that we can help you specifically and point out your mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj = {}, o, name;

for (var i in rawObject) {
    o = rawObject[i];
    name = o.name;
    if (! obj[name]) {
        obj[name] = [];
    }

    delete o.name;
    obj[name].push(o);
}
```

Comment: Colburton, this is really cool, I'll have to wrap my head aroud the delete o.name, basically you are deleting the name to get 0,1,2 indexes

Comment: @DanyD: `delete o.name` is called only because you don't want the objects in your result not to have a `.name` property any more. If that's not an issue, you should omit the property deletion (which is more costly than letting it stay).

Comment: Exactly, I was trying to get as close as possible to your example.